# rewriterule is not working in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am using .htacess file for rewrite url. i have written rewritrule that is working. but one issue with its. That is when page is completely loaded url in browser again changes in querystring format. my code is below. please help how can i set it.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z,0-9,-]+)/?$ /mysite.com/player.php?/$1/$2 [R]
```

i write this url

```
www.mysite.com/4/title
```

and its redirected into

```
www.mysit.com/player.php?/4/title
```

its working fine but when page loaded completely in browser address is again

```
www.mysite.com/player.php?/4/title
```

not remain in this format

```
(www.mysit.com/4/title)
```

Please help Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[R]` flag makes you physically redirect to the new address, rather than just rewriting the URL behind the scenes.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z,0-9-]+)/?$ /mysite.com/player.php?/$1/$2
```

This should work. Also, looks like you're using `,` as separator in the rewrite - that's unnecessary, you don't need separators between char types; you're actually matching `,` in the URL. If that's the designed behavior, you only need one comma (you have 2).

Comment: when i remove [R] then url remains same. actually on this page a lot of code created dynamically. by removing [R] only html code loaded and all code which is generated by jquery doesn't display. which way is to do this is there any other rule to write that one

Comment: Your problem is a different one then, we need to go over what's going on in your jQuery and the likes...

Comment: jquery print data which returned from server using ajax calls. that all code not executed when i write this rule without [R]

Comment: The problem is in your jQuery code, which frankly, I don't understand how it's related - your AJAX call URLs must be wrong now that the URLs are rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting yourself to the wrong URL by setting the R flag. That indicates that an external redirect should be forced. You could add the L flag instead, so no rewrite rules are executed after this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z,0-9,-]+)/?$ /mysite.com/player.php?/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: when i remove [R] then url remains same. actually on this page a lot of code created dynamically. by removing [R] only html code loaded and all code which is generated by jquery doesn't display. which way is to do this is there any other rule to write that one

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z,0-9,-]+)/?$ /player.php?/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Then make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: yes its working now. missing http:// i was using relative path. Now its correct Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's the reason I took that part out from my answer.

Comment: Also if it worked out can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: yes why not from your answer i get direction and solve my problem.

Comment: Hmm but you accepted an answer which is still not correct.